# How To Split an Array in half in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I need to split this array after it is sorted so that it prints something like

A: [8, 7, 6, 5]

B: [4, 3, 2, 1]

I know it might be simple but I cant figure it out. Do I need to do something like x.length / 2 ?

```
 import java.util.Arrays;


public class RecursiveMerge
{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int [] x= {8,7,5,6,2,4,3,1};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mergeSort(x)));



}

public static int [] mergeSort (int []a)
{
    if(a.length ==1)
        return a;
    else
    {
    int mid =  a.length/2;
    int [] left =mergeSort(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0 , mid ));
    int [] right =mergeSort(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, mid, a.length ));

    mergeSort(left);
    mergeSort(right);

    return merge (left, right);
    }
}
public static int[] merge (int[] left, int[] right)
{
int [] result = new int [left.length + right.length];

int leftPtr=0, rightPtr=0, resultPtr=0;


while(leftPtr < left.length && rightPtr < right.length)
    if (left[leftPtr] < right [rightPtr])
        result[resultPtr++] = left[leftPtr++];
    else
        result[resultPtr++] = right[rightPtr++];
while (leftPtr < left.length)
    result[resultPtr++] = left[leftPtr++];
while (rightPtr <right.length)
    result[resultPtr++] = right[rightPtr++];
return result;

}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make it dynamically, do it based on array length and split it in two:

```
int [] x= {8,7,5,6,2,4,3,1};
int len = x.length;

int a[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(mergeSort(x), 0, len/2);
int b[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(mergeSort(x), (len/2), len);

System.out.println("A: " + Arrays.toString(a));
System.out.println("B: " + Arrays.toString(b));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks it did, its exactly what i was trying to do

Comment: But, are you making the array smaller? Because in the method mergesort(int[] a), you are questioning about a.length.

Comment: I don't think you need to call `mergeSort` twice - just once, before the `copyOfRange`s, should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

An edit to the accepted answer could take into account that half an odd numbered int is actually the nearest, smaller, whole number, to the half. So, something like this is more appropriate:

```
int size = array.size();
int half = size % 2 == 0 ? size / 2 : (size / 2) + 1;
```